# Sharing same conversation with multiple bots

Tags: botframework

Question: How to have multiple bots supplying answers to the same Teams chat window a user has with an aggregator bot.

Description:
Several different teams have created bots that can answer questions related to their areas.  Picture a services bot, a catalog bot, etc.  All of these bots are maintained by their individual area owners, have their own sets of LUIS intents, etc.  That works great, but you have to know where to look for each type of question.

Now we'd like to have a single bot for anyone to connect to, to get their questions answered no matter what area the question falls into.  The idea is that this aggregator bot would then forward the questions to the appropriate area bot, which would then provide the answer.  The scenario here is that someone troubleshooting an issue could ask questions crossing multiple areas in the same place without having to know about each individual area's bot.

The bots are currently hosted in Teams and are C#.  So far, our solution has this flow:

1. Aggregator bot receives the question and asks each bot (through another endpoint specific to this flow) how confident it is that it can answer the question.
2. Aggregator bot decides which bot(s) to ask the question to, and sends the question off to the regular /api/messages endpoint for the bot.
3. [Broken] Area bot posts the answer/ auth prompt if needed/ or the start of a conversation to clarify the eventual answer.

We found the [bot-to-bot handoff](https://github.com/cmayomsft/BotToBot-Handoff) project, but in the readme.MD, it says:

> Note: The main bot and each of the sub-bots share the same AppID and
>   AppPassword. This allows all the bots to share the same conversation
>   ID, [`Dialog
>   Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.internals.idialogstack?view=botbuilder-3.8),
>   and [Bot State
>   Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state).

This is not possible in Azure, because you can't create multiple bots with the same AppId.

Trying a hack based on that, we found that if we change the bot configuration to use the same MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in the Application Settings in Azure for all the bots, then everything works fine through the aggregator bot. At that point, you can no longer connect directly to the individual bots anymore.  While that is clearly a hack and not a solution, it implies that the problem is authentication based and not something that is implicitly impossible.

There are lots of pieces around that seem like they might help, but we haven't found the documentation to fit them together.  This seems like something that should be a common scenario.  Ideally we could specify some kind of bot trust at a higher level and not have to specify AppId and AppPassword directly, though we're willing to do that in this case since we're all the same company.

Things we've tried:

1. Using TrustServiceUrl to trust the aggregator bot from each area
   bot, and all the area bots from the aggregator bot.  The call was
   made in Application_Start in Global.asax for each bot.
2. The hack described above
3. Specifying AppId and AppPassword in the BotAuthentication attribute

Number 3 actually solved the auth problem for letting the aggregator bot ask each bot for it's confidence in answering the question when we used it to tag those functions.  Specifying the AppId and AppPassword for the aggregator bot in the specification for that endpoint in the individual area bots worked great.  But it didn't fix the ability for the individual area bot to post back to the conversation owned by the aggregator bot.  In that case, the aggregator bot itself is consuming the answer, and it is an answer and not a flow.

What do we try from here?  Is there something we've missed, or is there something fundamentally wrong with the approach we've started with?

Comment: `But it didn't fix the ability for the individual area bot to post back to the conversation owned by the aggregator bot.` Does it throw exception when the individual area bot to post back?

Comment: Yes, to be clear the code snippet is:

await context.Forward(new AuthDialog(new ADALAuthProvider(), options, prompt), async (IDialogContext botAuthContext, IAwaitable<AuthResult> authResult) =>
            {
                var result = await authResult; 

And an exception fires on the await authResult that indicates an HTTP 403 occurred.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Bot Registration for each of the bots, then hosting them all within a single web application?  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2258#issuecomment-280506334

Comment: Sending an auth dialog from one bot, to have it displayed in another bot, would be a significantly complex message routing process due to the already complex routing process of an auth flow.

Comment: @EricDahlvang It works if I put the same AppId and AppPassword for all the apps.  So while it might be complex, that complexity seems to be handled by the framework already. It seems like the only missing piece is the authentication between the bots.  Hosting within the same web app COULD be done, and we will if we have to, but each bot is owned by a different team on different schedules with distinct LUIS configs, etc. Multiple bots prevents a bad change in one bot from breaking the whole set of bots.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but maybe you can implement a MultiCredentialProvider implementation with every bot's appid/password, and put that in every bot.  This way, when a message comes through, forwarded from a bot, it will be successfully authorized.